# method logical development in class

Tags: class, python-3.x, methods, pyqt5

Here is one simple code I do study. It's from zetcode.com

You need Pyqt5 lib to execute it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
ZetCode PyQt5 tutorial 

In this example, a QCheckBox widget
is used to toggle the title of a window.

author: Jan Bodnar
website: zetcode.com 
last edited: January 2015
"""

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QCheckBox, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):      

        cb = QCheckBox('Show title', self)
        cb.move(20, 20)
        cb.toggle()
        cb.stateChanged.connect(self.changeTitle)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('QCheckBox')
        self.show()


    def changeTitle(self, state):

        if state == Qt.Checked:
            self.setWindowTitle('QCheckBox')
        else:
            self.setWindowTitle('')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My question is more of class, args nature.

If you see this part of the code:

```
cb.stateChanged.connect(self.changeTitle)
```

it's obvious it is connected to changeTitle function, howerver in same function we have:

```
def changeTitle(self, state):
```

which starts with:

```
if state == Qt.Checked:
```

My question is about state. Why author added **state** and why does it act as an object, if not's defined in any way within this code.?

It would be logical to me, if author would do this:

```
cb.stateChanged.connect(self.changeTitle(state))
```

This way it would be known there are parameters which need to be executed based on if condition.

Would love to hear your explanations. Thank you.

Comment: Evidently `cb.stateChanged.connect` takes a *callback function*, i.e. a function that will be called on any change of `cb`'s state. When that call happens, a single argument is passed to the callback function, representing the new state. Hence the method you're passing defines a `state` argument to receive this. If you did try `cb.stateChanged.connect(self.changeTitle(state))` you would have two problems: 1. `state` isn't defined at that point; and 2. this would only call the callback once, before any changes of state actually happened.

Comment: Thank you. Yes it quiet evidently:), however, how do we know that technically? If i understand correctly, for all the methods which have callback nature, we can create an argument in (), which will act as trigger, response etc?

Comment: What do you mean *"know that technically"*? Read the docs? The source code? An event callback is a pretty common pattern in GUI frameworks.

Comment: Also your question *"we can create an argument in (), which will act as trigger, response etc?"* is incomprehensible to me.

Comment: well if i use `self.pusbutton.clicked.connect(self.buttonpressed)` and then define method, I would not need to add any additional argument. In this case, I suppose, this is not a callback method. I am just wondering, how do you know which `self.button` options support call back and most importantly, where do you check that. Thank you.

Comment: You read the documentation and/or source code of the library you're using.

Comment: I have checked documentation once again and i have found this: stateChanged(int state) thank you

Answer (score 0):

> If you see this part of the code:

```
cb.stateChanged.connect(self.changeTitle)
```

> it's obvious it is connected to changeTitle function,

Actually `self.changeTitle` is a method. Not that it changes anything, you could pass just any callable here.

> howerver in same function we have:

```
def changeTitle(self, state):
```

I assume you meant "in the same class" ?

> which starts with:

```
if state == Qt.Checked:
```

> My question is about state. Why author added state

"added" to what ???

> and why does it act as an object,

What do you mean "act as an object" ? (and BTW, are you aware that everything in Python is an object ?)

> if not's defined in any way within this code.?

It's an argument that is passed to the function. What puzzle you here ?

> It would be logical to me, if author would do this:

```
cb.stateChanged.connect(self.changeTitle(state))
```

Ok, I see... As I stated above, in Python everything (strings, ints, lists, etc, but also functions, methods, classes and even modules) is an object. Some objects are "callable" - they implement a `__call__(self, ...)` method. When you apply the call operator `()` to a callable object, it's `__call__` method is executed. Functions and methtods are (obviously) callable, as well as classes (calling a class being how you instanciate it).

IOW, given a function foo:

```
def foo(x):
   print("FOOO {}".format(x))
```

You can use it as an ordinary variable (pass it to another function etc), and you can then call it:

```
def bar(func):
    print("in bar, func is {}".format(func))
    print("calling func")
    func(42)


bar(foo)
```

if you look back at the original code:

```
cb.stateChanged.connect(self.changeTitle)
```

you can see that we are not *calling* `self.changeTitle` at this point (no parens...), we're just passing the method object to `cb.stateChanged.connect()`. When the `cb` object will deem it appropriate, it will call it back (whih is why it's named a "callback"), passing it the proper value for the `state` parameter.

Now what you suggest here:

```
cb.stateChanged.connect(self.changeTitle(state))
```

would not pass `self.changeTitle` (a method object), but instead first call `self.changeTitle(state)`, then pass the result of this call (the return value of `self.changeTitle(state)`) to `cb.stateChangedConnect()` - which is quite different.

NB : actually this would raise a `NameError` since `state` is not defined, but that's another problem.

> This way it would be known there are parameters which need to be executed based on if condition.

That's not how it works. It's the API that defines that callbacks passed to `cb.stateChangedConnect()` *must* accept a `state` param, and it's `cb.stateChangedConnect()` that passes this param.